# Large blob file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, large-files

I have an XHR object that downloads 1GB file.

```
function getFile(callback)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            callback.apply(xhr);
        }else{
            console.log("Request error: " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', 'download', true);
    xhr.onprogress = updateProgress;
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
    xhr.send();
}
```

But the File API can't load all that into memory even from a worker
it throws out of memory...

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    getFile(function() {
        var worker = new Worker("js/saving.worker.js");
        worker.onmessage = function(e) {
            saveAs(e.data); // FileSaver.js it creates URL from blob... but its too large
        };

        worker.postMessage(this.response);
    });
});
```

Web Worker

```
onmessage = function (e) {
    var view  = new DataView(e.data, 0);
    var file = new File([view], 'file.zip', {type: "application/zip"});
    postMessage('file');
};
```

I'm not trying to compress the file, this file is already compressed from server.

I thought storing it first on indexedDB but i i'll have to load blob or file anyway, even if i do request by range bytes, soon or late i will have to build this giant blob..

I want to create blob: url and send it to user after been downloaded by browser

I'll use FileSystem API for Google Chrome, but i want make something for firefox, i looked into File Handle Api but nothing...

Do i have to build an extension for firefox, in order to do the same thing as FileSystem does for google chrome?

---

Ubuntu 32 bits

Comment: Did it work when you downloaded a smaller \*.zip file? The error looks familiar for me, `"out of memory"`.

Comment: Yeah it worked, just for large realy

Comment: Hmm... can you try to alert anything when the btn click event fires? When the error gets thrown, give us the amount of alerts you got here

Comment: Why? console.log(this.response)... displays  the size of ArrayBuffer before send to worker.. normaly

Comment: No, I'm saying about the amount of alerts you get 'til it throws the error. I edited my comment before.

Comment: Just one error on console saying out of memory tho

Comment: I want to know how many alerts you get if you execute them in the `'click'` event of `btn`

Comment: The goal here is to download a large 1gb file - but what are you doing with a 1gb file in memory anyway? The only way to process this file is streaming it.

What is the intent of having this 1gb file using XHR and in memory? Need more clarity. Specifically what is this file and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Update a progress bar and how much was downloaded in %, send this file in a blob: scheme to user to download "fast", this url is generated by createObjectURL the parameter is a blob...

Comment: The browser already handles file downloads - just send them directly to the file i.e clicking on: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20160407/enwiki-20160407-pages-meta-history1.xml-p000000010p000002790.7z will download the 200MB file.
Are you building a download manager of some sort? The only way to do this is using partial content requests.

Comment: Yeah, i'm building it, but this content will be in ArrayBuffer right?... Soon i'll put alot array like new Blob([ArrayBuffer1, ArrayBuffer2, ...])

Comment: In the responsetype you chose arraybuffer, inside `if (xhr.status == 200) { }` you can get the file bytes from `xhr.response` - which is an `ArrayBuffer`

Comment: I think i found an article https://benramsey.com/blog/2008/05/206-partial-content-and-range-requests/ ... i'll read it

Comment: This isn't trivial. I can post an answer that will get you started though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122328/discussion-between-gabriel-dos-anjos-and-antonb).

Comment: "// FileSaver.js it creates URL from blob... but its too large" ... so it works up to that point?

Comment: Yeah, it works just stops with larger files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a theory that is if you split the file into chunks and store them in the indexedDB and then later merge them together it will work

A blob isn't made of data... it's more like pointers to where a file can be read from 
[image]

Meaning if you store them in indexedDB and then do something like this (using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) or alternative)

```
finalBlob = new Blob([blob_A_fromDB, blob_B_fromDB])
saveAs(finalBlob, 'filename.zip')
```

But i can't confirm this since i haven't tested it, would be good if someone else could

Comment: I have begun testing it. And I think it works :) help me review this issue: https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js/pull/18

Comment: I was trying too but i dont have time :/
The development is too late

Comment: From a file with 450MB it went well

Comment: finalBlob = new Blob([blob_A_fromDB, blob_B_fromDB]) - this row will create potentially huge blob in memory... On weak machines with small memory (RAM) this row will lead to browser crush.

Comment: @OlegYudovich not necessary. like i said, blob could be pointers to where the file is located on the disk. try this: create one or more file inputs (with maybe multiple file  selection). Select a few large (+GB) files from the your drive and merge them together and see if it would crash the browser and how fast/slow it is. the final blob would just be a container with information to where you can read chunkA + chunkB from

Answer (score 8):

Loading 1gb+ with ajax isn't convenient just for monitoring download progress and filling up the memory.

Instead I would just send the file with a `Content-Disposition` header to save the file.

---

There are however ways to go around it to monitor the progress. Option one is to have a second websocket that signals how much you have downloaded while you are downloading normally with a get request. the other option will be described later in the bottom

---

I know you talked about using Blinks sandboxed filesystem in the conversation. but it has some drawbacks. It may need permission if using persistent storage. It only allows 20% of the available disk that are left. And if chrome needs to free some space then it will throw away any others domains temporary storage that was last used for the most recent file. Beside it doesn't work in private mode.
Not to mention that it has been dropping support for it and may never end up in other browsers - but they will most likely not remove it since many sites still depend on it

---

The only way to process this large file is with streams. That is why I have created a [StreamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js). This is only going to work in Blink (chrome & opera) ATM but it will eventually be supported by other browsers with the whatwg spec to back it up as a standard.

```
fetch(url).then(res => {
    // One idea is to get the filename from Content-Disposition header...
    const size = ~~res.headers.get('Content-Length')
    const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('filename.zip', size)
    const writeStream = fileStream.getWriter()
    // Later you will be able to just simply do
    // res.body.pipeTo(fileStream)
    // instead of pumping

    const reader = res.body.getReader()
    const pump = () => reader.read()
        .then(({ value, done }) => {
            // here you know how large the value (chunk) is and you can
            // figure out the download speed/progress when comparing it to the size

            return done 
                ? writeStream.close()
                : writeStream.write(value).then(pump)
        )

    // Start the reader
    pump().then(() =>
        console.log('Closed the stream, Done writing')
    )
})
```

This will not take up any memory

Comment: Can i create an extension that do more and less the same thing for firefox? There's a work around?

Comment: Almost anything is possible with a firefox extension so i guess so. But i don't think people will install it :-/ you could contribute by helping firefox implementing streams instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

Blob is cool until you want to download a large file, there is a 600MB limit(chrome) for blob since it stores everything in memory.